# What do "POB", "to-zero", and some other terms mean?

Tags: support, terminology

What do the following abbreviations mean?

1. OP
2. NAA
3. MCVE
4. VLQ
5. POB
6. to-zero

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353

Comment: Can you give a context for the two words I left in the title? I have no idea what those refer to.

Comment: Can you provide some context for the "to-zero"? A link to a post, comment or chat message may be helpful.

Comment: @Andy http://imgur.com/vTfczLH

Comment: The question is closed for the wrong reason, but the first comment shows the duplicate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go read the [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms), but here's a very very short summary:

> OP

Original poster, AKA question-asker. That's you.

> NAA

Not an answer. Another flag reason

> MCVE

[Minimal, complete, verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

> VLQ

Very low quality. A flag reason.

> POB

Primarily opinion based. A close reason.

> to-zero

Yeah, I have no idea.

Comment: TIL what POB means! (Never saw that before. Odd.)

Comment: My best guess for to-zero: downvote until the score is 0, so the post gets deleted.

Answer (score 3):

OP is standard Internet slang for "Original Poster" or "Original Post", depending on context; usually this is the asker of a question, or the question itself, but sometimes it refers to an answer before some modification, or the author of that answer.

NAA stands for "Not An Answer", a flag that is raised on posts in the answer section that are not answers at all, to anything: other questions, comments on another post, etc.

MCVE is "[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)", explained more thoroughly at that page.

VLQ means "Very Low Quality", another flag that is usually raised on answers (occasionally questions too) that are so unusable they should probably be deleted as soon as possible. Random nonsense or posts that no one can even understand are the best examples of VLQ.